# Is there a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc such that $|f(z)|\rightarrow\infty$ as $|z|\rightarrow 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

When I learnt that there exists a holomorphic function on the unit disc $D$ that cannot be continuously extended to a domain that is strictly larger $D$, I was taught the example $$z\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}.$$ The reason why this function cannot be continuously extended is for at any root of unity $\xi$, there is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $\xi$ whose function values go to infinity and the roots of unity are dense on $\partial D$. This lead me to thinking that there should not be a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc such that $|f(z)|\rightarrow\infty$ as $|z|\rightarrow 1$, for otherwise such an $f$ would clearly be a holomorphic function on $D$ that cannot be continuously extended, and why bother with the above series?

So I tried to prove that there is not a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc such that $|f(z)|\rightarrow\infty$ as $|z|\rightarrow 1$, but could not get anywhere. Can anyone prove this assertion? Or is it false? Many thanks!

Comment: How about simply $log(1-z)$?

Comment: @MarsOneRover If e.g. $z\to -1$ then $\ln(1-z)\to\ln 2\ne\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

if $f$ exists consider $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ defined in open unit disk. It should be meromorphic and extendable to the closed unit disk with the value $0$ at the boundary.

Since it's zero on a line (has an accumulation point) it must be zero everywhere. So for $f$ to exist it would have to be $\infty$ everywhere.

This is but a sketch but i think it can be made rigorous.

Comment: Of course you could also interpret $f$ as a map from the closed unit disk to the Riemann sphere and see that on a line $f$ maps to a constant value in the Riemman sphere and so it has to be constant.

Comment: Makes sense, but, given the OP, then the series $1/(\Sigma z^{n!})$ would have infinitely-many zeros on the boundary and therefore be identically zero. What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: Instead use the Maximum Modulus Principle, after first getting rid of the zeros of $f$ inside the disk.

Comment: Since $|f(z)|\to \infty$ when $|z|\to 1$ then zeros of $f$ are separated from the unit circle. It gives only a finite number of zeros for $f$, that one can collect into the finite Blaschke product $B$ and consider $g=B/f$ which is holomorphic in the disc and zero on the circle, thus the identical zero.